# How do I use maven with this java project

Tags: java, maven

[image: Folder]
<sub>(source: [gyazo.com](http://gyazo.com/96d7e528c86d0dd1d3e995bba27332c9.png))</sub>

The basic tutorial on the maven website only shows how to make a new project from scratch. I'm confused about using maven with an existing project

I just want to compile the .java files into bin, not package them into a jar

Comment: Do you mean you want to compile the class files into the same directory as the source files?

Comment: sorry, meant to say bin, fixed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you set up the default maven configuration, the compiled .class files will be placed in target/classes.

Note: make sure your project has the correct layout for maven to work (without additional hassle):

```
project root
  - pom.xml
  - src
    - main
      - java
        - <.java classes and directories for packages>
```